# Apache Solr quickstart tutorial - error while loading main class SimplePostTool

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

I am following [Apache Solr quickstart tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html). The tutorial comes across indexing a directory of rich files which requires implementing     `java -Dauto -Drecursive org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool docs/` .

I am getting an error which says: `Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool` inspite of following the quickstart tutorial closely. I am not getting how to resolve the error and proceed ahead with the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented `java -classpath dist/solr-core-*jar -Dauto -Drecursive org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool docs/` rather than `java -Dauto -Drecursive org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool docs/`. The latter assumes that you have already set the environment for SimplePostTool using `export CLASSPATH=dist/solr-core-4.10.2.jar` whereas if you do not set the environment, there is no option other than implementing `java -classpath dist/solr-core-*jar -Dauto -Drecursive org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool docs/`

Thanks to the Apache user mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me

java -classpath example\exampledocs\post.jar -Dauto=yes -Dc=gettingstarted -Ddata=files  -Drecursive=yes org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool docs/