# Fail to load ExtractingRequestHandler when running the Solr Quickstart Tutorial

Tags: solr, classpath

I installed Solr 5.0.0 on OS X 10.10.2 using Homebrew. I am trying to follow the [quick start instructions](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html) and am getting errors when I try to index a directory of files.

I am able to successfully start the sample Solr server by running

```
bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt
```

as directed by the tutorial. I then try to index a directory of files by running

```
./bin/post -c gettingstarted docs/
```

(Note that this has to be done from the libexec subdirectory of the Solr install root.)

I get a server error 500 for every file it tries to add. The relevant stack:

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:492)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:423)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:559)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:632)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.createRequestHandler(RequestHandlers.java:326)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWrappedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:298)
    ... 30 more
```

The issue appears to be that ExtractingRequestHandler is not on the classpath.

ExtractingRequestHandler is in the solr-cell-5.0.0.jar.

```
jar tf dist/solr-cell-5.0.0.jar | grep ExtractingRequestHandler
org/apache/solr/handler/extraction/ExtractingRequestHandler.class
```

It's not clear to me if it needs to be on the classpath of the command doing the posting or the Solr instance. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982501/apache-solr-quickstart-tutorial-error-while-loading-main-class-simpleposttool) makes it sound like the latter. However, I tried setting

```
export CLASSPATH=dist/solr-cell-5.0.0.jar
```

before trying to index the files and saw the same error.

I don't see anything in the tutorial about how to configure this. What is the error and how do I get past it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is incorrect paths in the Solr example configuration. A workaround is to add softlinks from SOLR_ROOT/contrib and dist to the corresponding directories beneath SOLR_ROOT/libexec/contrib

Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886635/incorrect-directories-in-solr-5-0-0-example-configuration) and [here](https://cornercases.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/getting-the-solr-5-0-tutorial-to-work/).

Comment: First link is broken.