# Indexing Data in Solr for search

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am using solr search for my application while indexing data of example. 
But when I'm using

```
./post -c techproducts example/exampledocs/*.xml
```

I am getting

> java -classpath /home/s/Desktop/solr1/dist/solr-core-*.jar  -Dauto=yes
>   -Dc=techproducts -Ddata=files org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool example/exampledocs/gb18030-example.xml example/exampledocs/hd.xml
>   example/exampledocs/ipod_other.xml example/exampledocs/ipod_video.xml
>   example/exampledocs/manufacturers.xml example/exampledocs/mem.xml
>   example/exampledocs/money.xml example/exampledocs/monitor2.xml
>   example/exampledocs/monitor.xml example/exampledocs/mp500.xml
>   example/exampledocs/sd500.xml example/exampledocs/solr.xml
>   example/exampledocs/utf8-example.xml example/exampledocs/vidcard.xml
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool

Can anyone suggest something

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982501/apache-solr-quickstart-tutorial-error-while-loading-main-class-simpleposttool

Comment: Check this link as well  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6990

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847850/using-wildcards-in-java-classpath

Answer (score 1):

You can't use wildcards like this in classpath. Use `/home/s/Desktop/solr1/dist/*` or list explicitly all .jar files you need in your classpath. It's also possible to automate adding individual jars if needed (I assume you're on Linux):

```
CLASSPATH=`ls -1 /home/s/Desktop/solr1/dist/solr-core-*.jar | awk '{ ORS=":"; print; }'`
```

`java -classpath $CLASSPATH ...` and so on